# PayumBundle: Account is restricted - 10002

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I'm using PayumBundleSandbox with test credentials and everything works fine but when I change the credentials for the real, I get the following error "Account is restricted" to "L_ERRORCODE0": "10002".
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account restricted means that PayPal has flagged the account involved as problematic and is preventing it from processing transactions. It could be suspected of beig compromised (stolen credentials), or it could be suspected of being a fraudulent account, or many other things. If it is your account you can log into that account at PayPal to get more information about the restriction. If it is your customer's account, refer them to PayPal.